# MongoDB: find non exisiting or specific value

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x

I know about `$exists` in MongoDB but I don't know how to combine it with an OR logic within find().

I want to find all transactions where the `base_currency` field is either not existing or has a specific value. At the same time `trade_currency` must have a specific value. Here's what I tried but doesn't work.

```
txs = db.transactions.find({
    'base_currency': { $or: [{ $exists: true }, { $eq: base_currency }]},
    'trade_currency': currency
}).sort([('datetime_closed', 1)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $and combined with $or like this:

```
  db.transactions.find({
     "$and": [
         {"trade_currency" : currency},
         {"$or": [{"base_currency": {$exists: false}}, {"base_currency":base_currency }]},
     ]
  })
```

If you want to check that field is missing you have to use $exists: false